# Rails JSON Response Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I'm trying to build a simple API using Ruby on Rails which returns some statistics about tickets from an OTRS database.

Currently when I call my API for the following call, it is returning the below response.

**API Call**

```
http://localhost:3000/api/openvsclosed
```

**Current Response**

```
[[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]
```

I was wondering how I could get this to appear in the correct format of:

**Desired Response**

```
[
   {
      "Id":1,
      "Opened":1,
      "Closed":1
   },
   {
      "Id":2,
      "Opened":2,
      "Closed":2
   }
]
```

**Current Controller**

```
def openvsclosed
        sql =   "SELECT
                    @ROW := @ROW + 1 AS Id,
                    COUNT(t.tn) AS Opened,
                    COUNT(t.tn) AS Closed
                FROM
                    ticket t
                    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @ROW := 0) AS Row
                WHERE
                    t.create_time > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
                GROUP by
                    DAY(t.create_time)
                ORDER by
                    t.create_time;"
        records = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
        render json: records
    end
```

I'm quite new to using Ruby on Rails so I am most likely missing something obvious / big here.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking out [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) - you can customize a json template with whatever format you wish for the records you're returning from the controller to the json view.

In this case, you could do something like:

```
json.array! @records do |json, record|
  json.id record.id
  json.opened record.opened
  json.closed record.closed
end
```

Comment: This suggestion worked, but since @records is an array of arrays, you'd have to use json.id record[0] or something similar.  That is what I had to do in a similar example.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative is https://github.com/nesquena/rabl, simple to set up, and easy to use